# DBNull error for a column with value -Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, dbnull

While trying to update values in a DataTable that has "Book" records, i am continuously getting database DBNUll error for a column that has a value.
DB is made in Access and has following columns-

Book_ID -- Book_Name -- Book_Price -- Distributor_ID -- Book_Author -- Book_ISBN

Book_ID is the primary key. 
Book_ISBN is of type Double and is giving error. Here is the code that I am using -

```
    Dim DataValues As Data.DataRow = BookTableAdapter.GetData().Rows.Find(BookIdTxt.Text)
    BookNameTxt.Text = DataValues(1)
    PriceTxt.Text = DataValues(2)
    DistributorTxt.Text = DataValues(3)
    AuthorTxt.Text = DataValues(4)
    ISBNTxt.Text = DataValues(5)    '**This refers to ISBN column at database and throws error **here****
    ............................
    'Saving the data
    DataValues(1)  = BookNameTxt.Text
    DataValues(2)  = PriceTxt.Text
    ..
    ..
    BookTableAdapter.Update(DataValues())
```

Please let me know what could be the possible error. Thanks.

Comment: not enough code to be certain, but arrays start at index (0).  Hold the mouse over `DataValues` and it will show you the size, contents etc

Comment: Hey @Plutonix, i took care of that. Indexing is not the problem here I guess. While holding the mouse over DataValues, i can see that Datavalues(5) has not been retrieved properly. THis is what comes out -"The value for column 'Book_ISBN' in table 'Books' is DBNull." However, there is a value in that cell I am referring to

Comment: `DataValues` looks like it contains ROWS, but you are treating it like it is one rows of cell values.

Comment: 'DataValues As Data.DataRow = BookTableAdapter.GetData().Rows.Find(BookIdTxt.Text)' gives one row from the table. Also, all other fields are getting populated accurately.

Comment: Did you get this problem for any Book_ID or it is just for a particular one?

Comment: @steve, it is only for this particular column from the table. All other columns are getting proper values

Comment: If every record of the table exibit this behavior on that column then I would check the tableadapter to see if it is up to date with the structure of the database and if your connection is pointing to the correct database.

Comment: Hey Steve, that helped. As mentioned. ISBN is of type double. I had converted it from Integer to Double and refreshed TableAdapter. Somehow it generated two references to ISBN column- one bogus that is being refernced here and one original which got renamed to ISBN1. 
I made changes and it gets me values. However, now inde of ISBN is 10 - can this be changed to come at a specific place? I tried to modify the query to give ISBN as the 6th column but still index doesnt change.